# How to create numbered changelist using P4Python?

Tags: python, perforce

P4.fetch_change() creates a change spec with Change equal to 'new'. I need to create a change spec with an actual number (that won't collide with any other changes). IOW, I need to be able to reserve a changelist number.

How can this be done with P4Python?

Context: My script takes in an already-existing changelist number. I need to be able to test that the script works correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

P4.save_change() generates a changelist number -- that is, it creates a numbered, pending changelist. Try something like:

```
changespec = P4.fetch_change()
changespec[ "Description" ] = "placeholder"
P4.save_change( changespec )
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that `p4.fetch_change()` gives you the dict of the **current default changelist**!

You might already have files in there! So to really create an **empty** one you can just pass a dict with 'Change': 'new' and a 'Description'.

I couldn't find a way to make `save_change` return the actual changelist integer. So one can split the result and have the nr that way:

```
from P4 import P4

def create_empty_changelist(desc='some description'):
    p4 = P4()
    p4.connect()
    result = p4.save_change({'Change': 'new', 'Description': desc})[0]
    return int(result.split()[1])
```

Comment: Yes, your solution works! P4.fetch_change() add all items from the default changelist, which is very bad.

Comment: result = p4.save_change({'Change': 'new', 'Description': desc})[-1] ... its in the last element, example : ['*****\n* You must fix these errors before submitting:\n* - Extraneous line: Merge to: main: YES\n******', 'Change 7559 created.']

Answer (score 0):

Perforce doesn't allow you to reserve changelist numbers. If you want to submit an existing (pending) changelist using P4Python, do:
`p4.run_submit("-c", changelist)`